# DPA 4060: Protecting microdot connectors during traveling in the bag (connected to xlr adapter)

Tags: dpa, protect

Hi,

Currently I'm traveling and recording China.
I got quite a scare when the output of one of my Dpa 4060's was only 50% of the other mic level. I inspected the fragile microdot connector afraid it's phantom feed might have shortcircuited or something alike. It seemed fine and fortunately I found the culprit a little switch connecting the gain of the mic to the wrong channel.

It did however made me realise I need to protect the connector better, but I'm on the road without my local gear wizards around. Do you have any tips to keep my connectors from breaking or getting loose?

I'm thinking a soft paper layer plus a harder layer might do the trick. Any ideas anyone?

Thanks in advance!

Arnoud

Ps. Beijing is very quiet in the hutong and it's also great to record at night!

UPDATE!

Hi guys thanks for all the tips! I realised I didn't ask the right question, but you did provide me with a good answer! What I meant to ask was: how do you protect your microdot connector in the mix bag DURING shooting and traveling, with the microphones connected and ready to record. I went to the forbidden city with my recorder in my backpack and the wires were a bit bent in the process. What I've done now is put a small (ladies) pack pf tissues around the 2 connector/wires and tape that tight enough. This protects the wires and connectors in the hustle and bustle of busy metro stations and markets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We keep the whole set with accessories in the original DPA-case, but this might not be practical on the road.

For small connectors or other protruding fragile electronic things I have successfully used plastic bottle caps or ballpoint pen caps. Finding a cap with a tight fit is best, if not, you need a little tape or a rubber band to keep it on your item.

Cutting a piece of packaging foam to the right size has also worked for me. Might not last forever, but it's easy enough to make again.

Answer (score 1):

When I took my 4060s with me to Spain I found a small, plastic art supply case that was just large enough to carry the mics, connectors, some blu tack, and a couple additional mounts. There are moveable dividers in the case, so just a few tissues keeps everything from rattling around. I do like EMV's idea of pen caps for the microdot connectors though.

Answer (score 0):

Gaffer the connection carefully, roll them up and put them in a waterproof plastic bag (I used a plastic bag keeping food). It worked for me when I was travelling eastern europe with them.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B000GGMMB8/ref=mp_s_a_1?qid=1352797145&sr=8-24&pi=SL75

i personally use this, and i leave the xlr connected.